# SSRS Report Manager, login as a different user

Tags: internet-explorer-8, ssrs-2008, reportmanager

Microsoft's Report Manager documentation here:

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms157147(v=sql.105).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms157147%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

states to start Report Manager:

> 2.In the address bar of the Web browser, type the Report Manager URL. By default, the URL is http://{ComputerName}/reports.

The login failed using IE 8, because the user account apparently did not have the correct permissions.

If I try to login again, IE 8 continues to show the error message.

Is there anyway to force the browser to display the login dialog again? (Without closing the browser of course.) I did try using another instance of IE, and that also displayed the login failed error.

TIA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of discussions related to this problem on various forums. What solves the problem for one does not seem to necessarily solve the problem for another.

This Microsoft Connect post worked for me :

[User does not have required permissions. Verify that sufficient permissions have been granted and Windows User Account Control (UAC) restrictions have been addressed](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/622737/user-does-not-have-required-permissions-verify-that-sufficient-permissions-have-been-granted-and-windows-user-account-control-uac-restrictions-have-been-addressed)

Dealing with "User Account Control (UAC) restrictions" meant disabling UAC on the server.

Also, note there is an additional workaround mentioned. Users should run their browser as an administrator.

Answer (score 3):

This usually happens when the user does not have the required permissions, 

   But, it may also happen with a user with administrative rights.

Anyways, for accessing **Report Manager** for the very first time you may need to run the      browser as `Administrator` and then proceed with the URL.

HTH

Comment: Thank you. Ultimately, running IE8 as administrator was one of the things that I had to do in order to run Report Manager. However, running as an admin did not force (for me) IE8 to prompt for another user name / password if the login with the first set of credentials failed. (I did mark your answer has useful.) There seems to be no way to make the browser to prompt for alternative credentials.